# Using premake with multi localizations

Tags: localization, c++-cli, premake, satellite-assembly

I work with **premake 5** for few days now. I'm currently trying to port our VS2015 solution (mainly C++ native and CLI projects) to a premake 5 solution. I had no problem so far but now I'm not able to build resource libraries for all languages we localize our assemblies to. For example, if we have *fr* and *es* (for French and Spanich), we should have an assembly split like this:

- `foo.dll` (default, English),
- satellites `foo.resources.dll` for each other languages (separated in different folders of course).

But I'm not able (read: I don't know how) to write the lua script correctly.

Does someone know how to generate localized (AKA satellite) assemblies with premake5?

Thanks for your help!

---

**EDIT 1**

I added this to my lua script:

```
files({"/**.resx"})
```

It added the `.resx` files to the `.vcxproj` file but rather than being included like this:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="bar.resx"/>
```

they are included like this:

```
<None Include="bar.resx"/>
```

What's going on?

---

**EDIT 2**

I then added:

```
filter "files:**.resx"
    buildaction "Embed"
```

But it remains the same. I found [in premake 5 doc](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/buildaction) that `buildaction` was only supported in C# (my code is in C++/CLI). If this is true (it seems to be) is there a way to go deeper with my script to add, say, XML entries directly to the `.vcxproj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... after a lot of tries, I found a way. I just added a new (file) *category* for **EmbeddedResource** like this:

```
premake.vstudio.vc2010.categories.EmbeddedResource = {
    name = "EmbeddedResource",
    extensions = {".resx"},
    priority = 50, -- arbitrary number, I saw priorities are 0, 1, 2...

    emitFiles = function(prj, group)
        premake.vstudio.vc2010.emitFiles(
            prj,
            group,
            "EmbeddedResource",
            {premake.vstudio.vc2010.generatedFile}    -- cannot explain this...
       )
    end,

    emitFilter = function(prj, group)
        premake.vstudio.vc2010.filterGroup(prj, group, "EmbeddedResource")
    end
}
```

Hope it can help...